# Spring Implementation - Recurring Timer

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, timertask, spring-scheduled

I have seen various thread on timertask issues. However I would like some clarification on the inner working on spring Scheduler APIs (3.1).

I have a requirement to kick off a timer every 10 secs. The application runs in clustered websphere zos. (atleast 4 jvm nodes).

Here is the wiring.

```
<bean id="dataProcessSchedulerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="ondataTransferTimerWakeupService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="processDataFeedMetadata" />
</bean>

<bean id="DATA_PROCESS_TIMER"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="timerTask" ref="DATAProcessSchedulerTask" />
    <property name="delay" value="#{systemProperties.DATA_PROCESS_TIMER}" />
    <property name="period" value="#{systemProperties.DATA_PROCESS_TIMER}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
    <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
    list>
        <ref bean="DATA_PROCESS_TIMER" />
    </list>
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean id="onDATATransferTimerWakeupService" class="com.serviceimpl.OnDATATransferTimerWakeupService" />
```

I have defined (@async) for processDataFeedMetadata method.

The problem I am seeing the timer which fires every 10 secs correctly to begin with (4 jvms - 24 timer occurrences every min), started misbehaving after few hours (2 or 3 jvms stop firing any timer at all - 6 to 12 timer occurrences every min). I understand timertask implementation has it's own limitation. However, if I invoke an ASYNC method from MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean, Why would the timertask misbehave as 
(1) timer should complete well within the interval as soon as it invokes ASYNC method.
(2) I don't see any exception from app logs and MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean should have handled and consume any exception if there are any.

Really appreciate if anyone has input on what is going on here ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you utilizing Quartz Scheduler for Spring Scheduler implementation

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this problem with 1 jvm ?